# Is there a limit to how many hours a person can fly per month?

Tags: airline-operations

I'm trying to figure out whether there's a maximum per person.  Of course factoring in eight hours of sleep and say maintenance time there is definitely a limit, but I don't see where it is.

Comment: Each country will have its own regulations on this, and each airline may have its own policies, so it would help if you could narrow this down at least to a country.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Are you asking what's practically possible, or what's legally allowed? If you're asking about the legal part, please tell us which country you're asking about. And we do have some relevant questions already: [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/48429/62), [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1807/62)

Comment: Are you asking about how much a pilot is allowed to fly or a person can fly as a passenger?

Comment: @ymb1 How do you know the question is about the US? Or are you just making it about the US to benefit from the answer, even if we don't know the OP's intention?

Comment: @Pondlife - Didn't notice Farhan's comment about 'person'. Rolled it back and VTCed.

Comment: @ymb1 I think using a good answer is fine, if the OP doesn't follow up. I don't know if there's any SE etiquette that says we shouldn't.

Comment: Well, there certainly is because there are only so many hours per month.

Comment: Depending on the month, between 672 and 744 hours.

Answer (score 4):

With respect to air carrier operations in the US, 14 CFR 121.481 requires:

> (e) No pilot may fly as a member of a crew more than 100 hours during any one calendar month.
>
> (f) No pilot may fly as a member of a crew more than 1,000 hours during any 12-calendar-month period.

14 CFR 135.265 commuter:

> (1) 1,200 hours in any calendar year.
>
> (2) 120 hours in any calendar month.

Under Part 91, fractional ops, 14 CFR 91.1059 states:

> (a) No program manager may assign any flight crewmember, and no flight crewmember may accept an assignment, for flight time as a member of a one- or two-pilot crew if that crewmember's total flight time in all commercial flying will exceed -
>
> (1) 500 hours in any calendar quarter;
>
> (2) 800 hours in any two consecutive calendar quarters;
>
> (3) 1,400 hours in any calendar year.

Otherwise, there is no direct limit under Part 91. However, if you are fatigued enough to cause a problem, FAA can still charge you under general "unsafe operation" rules.