# Are there any duty time limitations on ferry pilots?

Tags: faa-regulations, ferry-flight

What FAA regulations are in force when a commercial pilot is being compensated to ferry a newly purchased aircraft?  Is there a limit on duty time?

Comment: Assuming that the ferry flight is a single-pilot operation under part 91 then [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/48429/62) answers it. If that doesn't help, please edit your question to add the regulations that will apply to the flight (91, 135, 121 etc.), the number of pilots and the type of aircraft.

Comment: @Pondlife I would think ferry flights would be flown with airline crew under Part 91.  Mentourpilot has a video about his new 737 ferry from Seattle to England on this.

Comment: @MikeBrass Ferry flights aren't just for airlines. Private aircraft are often ferried to the buyer as well, especially a buyer who needs instruction in an unfamiliar type and therefore shouldn't fly it home themselves.